# Should we consider reactant as the product of a no reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, equilibrium, aromatic-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution

If a reaction doesn't take place, should we call the reactant as the product? What is the convention? Let me illustrate the question with an example from JEE Advanced 2021, paper 1:

> The reaction of **Q** with $\ce{PhSNa}$ yields an organic compound (major product) that gives positive Carius test on treatment with $\ce{Na2O2}$ followed by addition of $\ce{BaCl2}.$ The correct option(s) for **Q** is(are)
>
> [image: A: 1-fluoro-2,4-dinitrobenzene; B: 1-iodo-3,5-dinitrobenzene; C: 1-bromo-3-(methylsulfanyl)-5-nitrobenzene; D: 4-(chloromethyl)-2-(methylsulfanyl)-1-nitrobenzene]

In option C, the usual S<sub>N</sub>Ar won't take place, but if we consider the substrate for the next step then it would give a positive test.

Also, can S<sub>N</sub>2 take place on carbon of $\ce{R-S-Me}$ and form $\ce{Ph-SMe}$ and $\ce{R-S-}$ anion? By thermodynamics, the equilibrium should lie in forward direction, but I don't know whether kinetics will support it or not.

Comment: You're overthinking it, to be honest, and that's probably why you realise it sounds a bit silly. If it doesn't react, there is no reaction, and no product. Ideally, you shouldn't have to resort to [philosophy / twisted logic / wordplay] (delete as you deem appropriate) to answer a question.

Comment: It would be helpful to say what the Carius test is for

Comment: Without the reactions conditions being specified this question is difficult to answer

Comment: What about the 2nd possibility of Sn2 that I mentioned?

Comment: I do not think that a likely reaction

Comment: @Govind I agree with your reopening reason, but please refrain from adding comments to your question framing your own question as "*silly*" or requesting mods to rush-review your post. If anything, your question (again, *not* a bad one, but a bit *strange*, I think) was closed by the community users, not mods, and the community users are as close as one gets to touch the aforementioned "spirit" of SE.

Answer (score 3):

For those who don't know the Carius test with addition of barium chloride is for organic sulfur.

Without the exact reaction conditions it is a bit difficult to be definitive however, it is clear that A & D will react with sodium thiophenoxide under mild conditions. I think this is the answer the question-setter expects. I think it possible with the right conditions, possibly using copper catalysis, that B could be persuaded to react. C will not react.